# Specify a Bundler version to be used in Capistrano

Tags: ruby, sinatra, capistrano, bundler, capistrano3

I'm using Capistrano to deploy a Sinatra app to hosting company (https://railsplayground.com/).

The hosting company supports 3 versions of Ruby:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13 revision 50299) [x86_64-linux]

$ /usr/local/bin/ruby224 -v
ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [x86_64-linux]

$ /usr/local/bin/ruby233 -v
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-linux]
```

As [Sinatra 2.0.3 requires Ruby >=2.2.0](https://rubygems.org/gems/sinatra/versions/2.0.3), I decide to use Ruby 2.3.3.  The hosting company has created related executables:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/ruby233 /usr/local/bin/gem233 -v
2.5.2

$ /usr/local/bin/ruby233 /usr/local/bin/bundle233 -v
Bundler version 1.14.4
```

To test the Gem-installation process, I created a folder with a Gemfile:

```
$ cat Gemfile
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'sinatra'
```

I ran bundler (`$ /usr/local/bin/ruby233 /usr/local/bin/bundle233 install --path=vendor/bundle`) and the gems were install the in application's `vendor/bundle` directory:

```
$ ll vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/
total 28
drwxrwxr-x 7 foobar foobar 4096 Sep 10 06:35 ./
drwxrwxr-x 9 foobar foobar 4096 Sep 10 06:35 ../
drwxrwxr-x 5 foobar foobar 4096 Sep 10 06:35 mustermann-1.0.3/
drwxrwxr-x 7 foobar foobar 4096 Sep 10 06:35 rack-2.0.5/
drwxrwxr-x 3 foobar foobar 4096 Sep 10 06:35 rack-protection-2.0.3/
drwxrwxr-x 4 foobar foobar 4096 Sep 10 06:35 sinatra-2.0.3/
drwxrwxr-x 7 foobar foobar 4096 Sep 10 06:35 tilt-2.0.8/
```

Next, I created a simple Sinatra application and attempted to deploy it.

`Gemfile`:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

gem "sinatra"

group :development do
    # deployment
    gem 'capistrano'
    gem 'capistrano-bundler'
    gem 'capistrano-passenger'
end
```

`config.ru`:

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.setup

# desired
#/usr/local/bin/ruby233 /usr/local/bin/bundle233 install --path=vendor/bundle

require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'app')
run Sinatra::Application
```

`deploy.rb`:

```
set :git_user, 'foobar'
set :application, "cap"
set :repo_url, "git@bitbucket.org:#{fetch(:git_user)}/#{fetch(:application)}.git"
set :branch, 'master'
set :passenger_restart_with_touch, true
```

`staging.rb`:

```
set :stage, :staging
set :ssh_user, 'foobarbaz'
set :use_sudo, false
server "supersonic.webhostserver.biz", user: fetch(:ssh_user), roles: %w{app, web, db}
set :tmp_dir, "/home/#{fetch(:ssh_user)}/tmp"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{fetch(:ssh_user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
```

I ran the staging deployment (from workstation):

```
$ bundle exec cap staging deploy
```

When the script attempts to install the Gems, it fails:

```
00:14 bundler:install
      01 bundle install --path /home/foobarbaz/apps/cap/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet
      01 stdin: is not a tty
      01 An error occurred while installing mustermann (1.0.3), and Bundler cannot
      01 continue.
      01 Make sure that `gem install mustermann -v '1.0.3'` succeeds before bundling.
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as foobarbaz@supersonic.webhostserver.biz: bundle exit status: 5
bundle stdout: An error occurred while installing mustermann (1.0.3), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install mustermann -v '1.0.3'` succeeds before bundling.
bundle stderr: stdin: is not a tty
```

It fails because `mustermann` requires Ruby >= 2.2.0, but the script is attempting to install the Gem using Ruby 2.0 (the default).

How do I get capistrano (version 3.11.0 on my workstation) to use the desired version of bundler (bundle233) on the server?

Comment: are you using a version control for ruby like `rvm` or `rbenv`? If so there are gems that plug this into `capistrano` ([rvm](https://github.com/capistrano/rvm) or [rbenv](https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv)) allowing you to specify the ruby version which is your real issue. If not try this https://coderwall.com/p/krkw7a/setting-ruby-version-in-capistrano-3

Comment: It would make things a lot easier, but no, they don't support either of these.  I'll try the `ruby_version` option.